# How to make console process not open?

Tags: c++, c, windows

So, I'm trying to learn how to make C/C++ Windows Desktop Applications, but I have come across a great issue, when creating a completely normal window, the cmd where the console application would run appears. Is there any way to make so that it doesn't even open? I've been seeing some methods, but they appear to hide the console, but the process is still there.
Here is my code:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR args, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"windowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    
     if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"windowClass", L"Window 1",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100,
        256, 256,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg = { 0 };

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check linker options, make sure you are passing [`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem) and not `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`

Comment: The comment above is for MSVC. If you use MinGW, pass `-mwindows`.

Comment: It's probably MinGW. With `WinMain` as the entrypoint, it's unlikely that MSVC (VC++) would be building a console app (which has absolutely nothing to do with "cmd" by the way; please try to be more curious and think for a second about all those conhost.exe instances you see in the process list); it's certainly not the default behavior.

Comment: Yes, it was, and I solved it with your help! Thanks